# how to update master page in all child pages without refreshing

Tags: asp.net

As i am new to asp.net i need some help from you,
i am using a `MasterPage` and child pages.

In master page I have a `Label` in which it shows the items added to cart. 
when i am adding a product in products page.aspx it is updated in master page as (1 item) and showing in the label but when i am coming to `homepage.aspx` it is not showing i am using same master page in `home.aspx`.
If i refresh the `home.aspx`, it is updated. I need to update it without refreshing.

Comment: can you show the code that updates the label text?

Answer (score 0):

Sample code look like this

**MasterPage markup:** Here's the label in your masterpage which you want to be update from childpage

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

**MasterPage.cs:**

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public string labeltext
    {
        get
        {
            return Label1.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            Label1.Text = value;
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**ChildPage.cs:**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Master.labeltext = "Your value"; // set your value
    }
```

Comment: But it is updated on load so we need to refresh. I want it without refreshing the page ia there any solution

Comment: @user2944187: how you set the value ?? on which event, you can write this on that event